# Rotated rectangle is shifted (SVG - rotation matrix)

Tags: go, svg, rotation, image-rotation

I use SVG to work with some formulars. When I rotate a rectangle, the rectangle is shifted...

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
)
type Point struct {
    X, Y float64
}

/* With SVG path the points are
    A B
    D C
*/
type Rect struct {
    A Point
    B Point
    C Point
    D Point
}

func (r *Rect) Rotate(a float64) {
    r.A.X = r.A.X * math.Cos(dToR(a)) - r.A.Y * math.Sin(dToR(a)) 
    r.A.Y = r.A.X * math.Sin(dToR(a)) + r.A.Y * math.Cos(dToR(a))

    r.B.X = r.B.X * math.Cos(dToR(a)) - r.B.Y * math.Sin(dToR(a)) 
    r.B.Y = r.B.X * math.Sin(dToR(a)) + r.B.Y * math.Cos(dToR(a))

    r.C.X = r.C.X * math.Cos(dToR(a)) - r.C.Y * math.Sin(dToR(a)) 
    r.C.Y = r.C.X * math.Sin(dToR(a)) + r.C.Y * math.Cos(dToR(a))

    r.D.X = r.D.X * math.Cos(dToR(a)) - r.D.Y * math.Sin(dToR(a)) 
    r.D.Y = r.D.X * math.Sin(dToR(a)) + r.D.Y * math.Cos(dToR(a))
}

// degree to radian
func dToR(deg float64) float64 {
    return deg * (math.Pi / 180.0)
}

// radian to degree
func rToD(rad float64) float64 {
    return rad * (180.0 / math.Pi)
}

func writeSvg(data []byte) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("test.svg", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    _, err = f.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}


func main() {

    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.WriteString("<svg width=\"600\" height=\"600\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">")
    b.WriteString("<g stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"2.5\" fill=\"none\">")
    b.WriteString("<path d=\"M")
    
    r := &Rect {
        Point{-200, -100},
        Point{200, -100},
        Point{200, 100},
        Point{-200, 100},
    }
    
    moveX := 300.0
    moveY := 300.0
    
    r.Rotate(30)
    
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%.14f %.14f L", moveX+r.A.X, moveY+r.A.Y))           
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%.14f %.14f ", moveX+r.B.X, moveY+r.B.Y))  
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%.14f %.14f ", moveX+r.C.X, moveY+r.C.Y))   
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%.14f %.14f Z", moveX+r.D.X, moveY+r.D.Y))

    b.WriteString("\"/>\n")   
    b.WriteString("</g></svg>")


    err := writeSvg(b.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The results look like this (black rectangle)

[image]

The rectangle is rotated, but angles are not 90 degree ... it's a simple and well documented formula, but i can't find my bug.

(There are other ways in SVG to draw and rotate things, but I work with the formulars.)

Comment: I think you are rotating every vertex around a point {0,0} and redraw the shape. In SVG you can use the transform attribute to rotate a shape https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#rotate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Rotate` function you calculate the new `x`, `y` coords incorrectly. You calculate `r.A.X` based on the current value of `r.A.X` and `r.A.Y` and then you calculate `r.A.Y` based on the new value of `r.A.X`, and that throws you off.

You need to know the original `x`, `y` values and then calculate the new values based on those.

```
rad := dToR(a)

x, y := r.A.X, r.A.Y
r.A.X = x*math.Cos(rad) - y*math.Sin(rad)
r.A.Y = x*math.Sin(rad) + y*math.Cos(rad)
```